# Дублирование запросов AjaxForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net

```
    @model List<Diplom.Models.ViewModel>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreditCPU", "Credit", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "sendPost" }))
{
    <form>
        <section style="margin-top:30px">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1>Введите данные</h1>
                </div>
                @if (Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1).uniqId != 0)
                {
                    <input class="form-control invisible" name="idCpu" value="@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1).uniqId" />
                }
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Наименование:</td>
                            <td><input name="nameCpu" type="text" id="nameCpu" class="form-control" value="@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id==1).Name"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Разьем:</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="socketid" id="socketid" class="form-control">
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        if (item.socket != null)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.id" id="@item.id">@item.socket</option>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ядер,шт:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cores" id="cores" class="form-control" value="@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id==1).core"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Стоимость</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" value="@Decimal.Round(Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id==1).price.GetValueOrDefault(),2)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Количество:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="count" id="count" class="form-control" value="@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id==1).count"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Производитель:</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="idManufacture" id="idManufacture" class="form-control">
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        if (item.brand != null)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.id">@item.brand</option>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary cpuform" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </form>
}<script>                $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#socketid").val(@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1).idsocket);
});

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#idManufacture").val(@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1).idbrand);
});
```

Это modalbox. Подгружается через PartialView в другое представление, сюда:

```
<div id="modDialog" class="modal fade">
<div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div></div>
```

Подгружается оно, если нажать на кнопку "редактировать запись" в таблице.
При нажатии на кнопку "сохранить",в первый раз выполняется, 1 Post запрос,
далее скрипт скрывающий окно:

```
function sendPost(e) {
    $("#dialogContent").modal('hide');
    $("#modDialog").modal('hide');
}
```

Всё ок, нажимаем еще раз "редактировать запись", редактируем, нажимаем "сохранить", уже отправляется 2 Post запроса с теми-же данными.
В 3 раз уже 3 запроса, и так далее...

Грешил сначала на то, что скрипт выполняется несколько раз, т.к. форм несколько.
Но по факту даже с этим:

```
$('.modal').remove();
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('body').removeClass("modal-open");
```

Ничего не изменилось.

P.S. Post запрос отправляет только одинаковые\последние данные
P.S.S. Смотрел точками останова, сколько раз запрашивается форма, 1 раз, но 
POST запросы и вызовы функции он запускает несколько раз.

Comment: Попробуйте сразу загружать частичное представление скрыто, а при нажатии "редактировать запись" его делать видимым.

Answer (score 0):

Решением проблемы стало удаление

```
"<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>"
```

из представления, и перенос его на уровень вверх(можно и в отдельный файл скриптов)

Может кому поможет, кто столкнется с такой проблемой